# How to get a ReadMe.txt or any file into the \bin\debug directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have added file to the solution but sure where to add it so Team VS
will ensure it gets into \bin\debug directory....

Answer (score 3):

In the file properties (click the file, then `F4`), under `Copy to Output Dirctory` set it to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

This ensures that file is copied to the output directory (`Debug` or `Release` normally).

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer, right click on the file and select Properties, then in the field called "Copy To Output Directory" select "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer".